# Python bindings for Clojure

Tags: python, clojure

When binding python in clojure, I encounter the following error. Please comment how to resolve this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to resolve symbol: boolean? in this context, compiling (tech/v2/datatype/casting.clj:154:5)
```

The configuration as following

a. project.clj

```
  .....
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [environ             "1.1.0"]
                 [clj-python/libpython-clj "1.44"]]
  .....
```

b. core.clj

```
(:require [clojure.core.async :refer [<!!]]
            [clojure.string :as str]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]
            [libpython-clj.require :refer [require-python]]
            [libpython-clj.python :as py :refer [py. py.. py.-]])
  .....
```

Comment: Add the `lein-ancient` plugin to all projects and use it regularly to find outdated dependencies:  https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `boolean?` was added in Clojure 1.9:

```
$ clj
Clojure 1.10.1
user=> (-> #'boolean? meta :added) 
"1.9"
```

Since you are using `1.8` this function is not available.

Comment: thanks for your help. I found there are many errors after upgrade all dependencie "[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]  [environ "1.2.0"] [morse  "0.4.2"] [clj-python/libpython-clj "1.44"]". I am going to figure out what are the problems. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I got a new error message ""Syntax error (ExceptionInfo) compiling at (libpython_clj/metadata.clj:13:1).\nFailed to load library\n","

Comment: You can ask on Zulip. https://clojurians.zulipchat.com. Chris, the author is quite active on the data-science and libpython-clj-dev streams. Most of the community is there.

Comment: @zcaudate Thank you for your comment.